# Get all groups that have the maximum count

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose now I have a table T which is like this:

```
A|B
1|1 
1|2 
2|1 
2|2 
2|3 
3|1 
3|2 
3|3
```

With `select A, count(*) from T group by A` we should get:

```
A|count(*)
1|2
2|3
3|3
```

Now I need to get the last two rows in the previous query -- which have the maximum value of `count(*)`. How can I do this in a single query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH recordList
AS
(
    SELECT  A, COUNT(*) totalCount,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
    FROM    tableName
    GROUP BY A
)
SELECT  A, totalCount
FROM recordLIst
WHERE rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68b42/3)

Comment: what is the difference between `DENSE_RANK` and `RANK`?

Comment: RANK will show gaps in the event of ties, DENSE_RANK will not. In this case it is irrelevant because we're only after the first partition, so gaps are not possible.

Comment: see here for [TSQL Ranking Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx), basically `DENSE_RANK` result has no gaps in the ranking but the OP is interested on the greatest maximum count so either of the two will do.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH a(A,C,R) AS
(
  SELECT A, COUNT(*), RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
  FROM dbo.T GROUP BY A
)
SELECT A, C FROM a WHERE R = 1;
```

Comment: +1 for the ranking, matters when number of rows are unknown. `C=count(*)` even nicer for Syntactic sugar :-)